# Calling out perceived snarkiness--should I bother?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I called out what I considered a snarky comment on this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/41987326/438992

The original poster has since deleted his comments and left me with serial downvotes in return. I've been trying pretty hard to be consistently nice lately, and attempting to moderate how people are coming across, etc.

The question: is it "our" job to call stuff like this off as a way of letting (relative) newcomers know that comments made in text don't necessarily convey what they're actually thinking and that sometimes a small change in wording can make a lot of difference?

Or should they just be flagged, even if it's relatively minor snark, and not bother?

*Edit*

My issue with "just" flagging is that if the comment is removed by a moderator they don't (necessarily) have anybody telling them that what they're saying is *really* easy to misinterpret (if snark wasn't their intent) or that it's just not necessary to be snarky if their suggestion isn't relevant (which it wasn't).

Without education, moderation isn't as valuable.

Comment: Don't "call someone out" because you think they didn't phrase something well.  Politely point out how they can improve something they said.  If you go around trying to pick fights with people because they weren't posting a constructive comment, don't be surprised if it doesn't end well (for anyone).

Comment: IIRC, moderators can send a user a message if they feel it's necessary. If they feel the need to message someone after repeated "non-constructive" flags, they can do that.

Comment: _"...and attempting to moderate how people are coming across, etc."_ - That's a problem. It is not your job nor is it mine to "moderator" how people post comments. Are there rude, unacceptably comments? Certainly. But let's let the diamond mods deal with them, instead of starting flame wars in the comments. Flag the comment if you think it is rude and/or offensive, and go one. No sense in getting yourself worked over someone else's rude behavior.

Comment: People can be dicks, flag it and let the mods sort it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or should they just be flagged, even if it's relatively minor snark, and not bother?

Yes, flag the comments as non-constructive (or rude if they cross the line), and walk away.

The problem is, if you respond to such comments it usually gets heated, ending with blood (i.e. revenge downvotes or alike).

It's certainly possible that their comment wasn't snarky from their perspective, but then got somewhat "triggered" by your response.

Answer (score 7):

No, it's not your job to call people out in comments and try to shame people for what you think is an inappropriate comment.

Flag the comment if you think that it's inappropriate and merits deletion.

If you think you can constructively point out a potential problem with a user's comment in way that they would find constructive and informative, such that they would be able to more effectively convey information in the future, then...maybe, although that's getting pretty off topic in the comment thread, and it's just so unlikely to not end up being (or turning into) an unconstructive argument; personally I'd shy away from trying to do this.

Comment: My original comment asked only why they were mad (or upset, I forget what they said). They asked why I thought that, I told them. TJ pointed out why the suggestion was pointless, they responded with snark. I don't see the point in (a) that kind of response, and (b) nobody actually *telling* them that they're being snarky. If the comment just disappears due to moderation, nothing is learned. There isn't anything in my comments I think could be construed as intending to cause "shame" up until they started name-calling.

Comment: @DaveNewton So you think the appropriate response to someone posting a snarky comment is for you to post a snarky comment?  You're sure about that?

Comment: What did I say that was snarky? Once he called me a piece of shit I said I found it amusing, which is true, and not snarky.

Comment: @DaveNewton That sure sounds snarky to me.  Calling someone a piece of shit isn't snarky, that's just offensive, and clearly the person saying that *know* that.  The *point* of saying that to someone is to try to offend them.  You poking fun at the person who's insulting you is  you being snarky (not necessarily *offensive*, but certainly *snarky*).

Comment: @DaveNewton - If a conversation is trending in a bad direction, the best thing you can do is flag the comments involved and walk away. Continuing to engage them usually leads to a downward spiral. I cleaned up most of the comments here, the person responsible for the serial downvotes has been warned, and the system should invalidate those over the next day.

Comment: _“Flag the comment if you think that it's inappropriate and merits deletion.”_ — I have recently flagged a comment that read like _“This is a very hard problem with an incredibly difficult answer”_ to a beginner’s question as rude, yet the flag was declined. It added nothing to the post and was just snark, nothing more.